# How to define test methods using Python Unittest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class CorrecaoEfetivaNota(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/r13/dev/chromedriver')

def teste_login_avaliador(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("")
    cpf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="CPF"]')
    cpf.send_keys("")
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="SENHA"]')
    password.send_keys("")
    login = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
    login.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

def teste_buscar_mais_um(self):
    driver = self.driver
    buscar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[1]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")
    buscar.click()

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()
```

I'm trying to write this tests in Python, the first function is ok, but the second one inside the class is not being executed in the tests. How can I organize this?

Comment: Update your question with correct indentation

Comment: Also try `test_login_avaliador` method name instead of `teste_login_avaliador` (and `test_buscar_mais_um` instead of `teste_buscar_mais_um`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with Python and **unittest** module with *Selenium* you have to consider a few facts as follows :

- Indentation for *class* and `test_method` are different.
- Instead of `driver.close()` always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- If you are using **unittest** module you have to call the **`__main__`**.
- Here is your own code with the required minor modifications which will execute the *first method* **`teste_login_avaliador()`** as well as the *second method* **`teste_buscar_mais_um()`** within the *Class* **`CorrecaoEfetivaNota()`**:

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  class CorrecaoEfetivaNota(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

      def teste_login_avaliador(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get("http://d3dyod5mwyu6xk.cloudfront.net/")
          cpf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="CPF"]')
          cpf.send_keys("27922797885")
          password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="SENHA"]')
          password.send_keys("enccejaregular")
          login = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
          login.click()
          driver.implicitly_wait(3)

      def teste_buscar_mais_um(self):
          driver = self.driver
          buscar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[1]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")
          buscar.click()

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Note: Though both the **test_methods** are being called still you will face the following exception:

  ```
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//section[1]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button"}
  ```
- At the line:

  ```
  buscar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[1]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")
  ```

  This exception can be solved easily following the actual *Test Steps* of your *usecase* and if required you can raise a new question/ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You write that the first function is ok, which I assume must be the `setUp()` function you are referring to (provided that in your code you indented correctly).

As Andersson comments, your unittest methods needs to begin with "test_" not "teste_". Providing "test_" is your way of telling `unittest` that this method should be tested.

In your `unittest` you probably also want to test something such as `self.assertEqual(1,1)` otherwise your tests will pass no matter what.

Next time please provide us with a more thorough description of what is wrong. How did you make the call to unittest? What error is python giving you? What result did you expect? Etc. It makes solving your problem much faster.

I encourage you to make a simple test first and ensure that it runs:

```
import unittest

class TestingUnittest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    print("SetUp called")

  def tearDown(self):
    print("tearDown called")

  def test_Method(self):
    print("Testing 1==1")
    self.assertEqual(1,1)
```

Call this from your terminal:

```
>>>python -m unittest "name-of-test.py"
```