# How can I define send_keys for python function?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I need advice on how to call send_keys for user input. If I assign a variable for the line `self.browser.find_elements_by_id ("Login1_UserName")` and then send it to send_keys, the solution does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
 def login(Self):
     # login to the app
     username = self.browser.find_elements_by_id ("Login1_UserName")
     username.send_keys ("userone")
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

`find_elements_*` would return a *List* and you can't invoke `send_keys()` on a *List*. So you need to replace `find_elements_*` with **`find_element_*`** and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
def login(Self):
    # login to the app
    self.browser.find_element_by_id("Login1_UserName").send_keys("userone")
```

As per best practices, while invoking `send_keys()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Login1_UserName"))).send_keys("Tomasito")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Login1_UserName"))).send_keys("Tomasito")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Login1_UserName']"))).send_keys("Tomasito")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: ok, Thank you. Its very usable. I have two features:

  `def testTitle(self):
        self.browser.get("http://localhost/test")
        self.assertEqual("Login",self.browser.title)
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Login1_UserName"))).send_keys(
            "Tomasito")`

    `def Login(self):
        # login to app
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("Login1_UserName").send_keys("userone")`

It only works if this line is in the function testTitle and not in my newly created Login function for separate logging.

Comment: @Tomasito Are you using Python's _unit-test_ module?

Comment: For [tag:python-unittest] See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859370/python-webdriver-no-browser-launched-while-using-unittest-module/49860022#49860022), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503046/what-is-unittest-in-selenium-python/49516313#49516313) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562186/how-to-define-test-methods-using-python-unittest/52563091#52563091) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used `find_elements_by_id("Login1_UserName")` it will return list  NOT the element.You should use `find_element_by_id("Login1_UserName")`

```
def login(Self):
     # login to the app
     username = self.browser.find_element_by_id("Login1_UserName")
     username.send_keys("userone")
```

---

Try this code see if this work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome("path of chrome driver")
driver.get('url')
username=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'Login1_UserName')))
username.send_keys("userone")
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work ... the test runs, but it doesn't even write a character.

Comment: I don't get any error, the whole test runs out, but it doesn't write me anything in the username field.

Comment: This because you need to provide some wait time `WebDriverWait `

Comment: is it possible that this is because the definition of self.browser.get I have in another function? Because if you move this command there, it will be done.