# setUpClass(cls) function block not getting executed using python-unittest through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

Trying to run the below Selenium code in pycharm, the test is getting executed with no errors but the functions defined inside the class GoogleSearch is not being executed.
Need help in finding what is the issue!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest


class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    print("123")

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("456")
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_search_automationstepbystep(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation Step by Step")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    def test_search_kiranmallaiah(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Kiran Mallaiah")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.time.sleep(3)
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()


print("Test Completed")
```

The below is the output:

```
C:\Users\Indrani\PycharmProjects\SeleniumProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/Indrani/PycharmProjects/SeleniumProject/Sample Projects/GoogleSearchTest.py"
123
Test Completed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things you need to consider while using [python-unittest](/questions/tagged/python-unittest)

- The [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module is extensively used for constructing and running testcases.
- A testcase is created by subclassing [unittest.TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase). The tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`.
- The [setUp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) and [tearDown()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) methods allow you to define instructions that will be executed before and after each test method.

---

However you missed the most **important** part to set the `__name__` variable to have a value and define which *test functions* to execute. In order to configure those you need to add a couple of lines as follows:

- `if __name__ == '__main__':`: This line sets the `__name__` variable to have a value `"__main__"`. If this file is being imported from another module then `__name__` will be set to the other module's name. You will find a detailed discussion in [What does if **name** == "**main**": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?)
- `unittest.main()`: Invokes the *test functions* from the configured module.

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest


class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    print("123")

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("456")
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_search_automationstepbystep(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation Step by Step")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    def test_search_kiranmallaiah(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Kiran Mallaiah")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.time.sleep(3)
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

print("Test Completed")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Execution order of python unitests by their declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521461/execution-order-of-python-unitests-by-their-declaration/60530370#60530370)
- [What is unittest in selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503046/what-is-unittest-in-selenium-python/49516313#49516313)
- [How to define test methods using Python Unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562186/how-to-define-test-methods-using-python-unittest/52563091#52563091)